# Checking if object array contains certain key inside for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

My cart data is something like this

```
{
    "cart" : [{
        "productId":"64d3a241c281d1adba26b454",
        "color":"pink",
        "count":1,
        "size":40

    },
    {
        "productId":"64d3a241c281d1adba26b454",
        "color":"blue",
        "count":3
//this object has no property named 'size'

    }]
}
```

My addToCart function is

```
const addToCart = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { cart } = req.body;
  const { _id } = req.user;
  console.log(cart)
  console.log(_id)
  let products = [];
  const user = await User.findById(_id);
 
  for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
    let object = {};
    object.product = cart[i]._id;
    object.color = cart[i].color;
    object.size = cart[i].size 
    products.push(object);//products array should contain all objects(with and without size property)
  }
  let cartTotal = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    cartTotal = cartTotal + products[i].price * products[i].count;
  }
  let newCart = await new Cart({
    products,
    cartTotal,
    user: user?._id,
  }).save();
  res.status(201).json({
    status: "success",
    data: {
      newCart,
    },
  });
});
```

How can i check if the property 'size' is present in every object of cart object array inside loop. I want all objects with size property and without size property to be added to products array

Comment: *"I want all objects with size property and without size property to be added to products array"*: so there is no difference in what you want to do with these objects? How is `size` relevant to what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should do the job for you If I understood your problem .
To check if the 'size' property is present in each object of the cart array and then add them to the products array accordingly, you can modify your loop like this:

```
const addToCart = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { cart } = req.body;
  const { _id } = req.user;
  console.log(cart);
  console.log(_id);
  let products = [];
  const user = await User.findById(_id);

  for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
    let object = {};
    object.product = cart[i]._id;
    object.color = cart[i].color;
    
    // Check if 'size' property is present in the current object
    if ('size' in cart[i]) {
      object.size = cart[i].size;
    }

    products.push(object);
  }

  let cartTotal = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    cartTotal = cartTotal + products[i].price * products[i].count;
  }

  let newCart = await new Cart({
    products,
    cartTotal,
    user: user?._id,
  }).save();
  res.status(201).json({
    status: "success",
    data: {
      newCart,
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) in JavaScript to achieve this. When looping the array of objects, use this to check "size" property exist or not.

```
let propertyToCheck= 'size';

for (let i = 0; i < cartCollection.length; i++) {

if (cartCollection[i].hasOwnProperty(propertyToCheck)) {
    console.log(`${i} has the key "${propertyToCheck}"`);
} else {
    console.log(`${i} does not have the key "${propertyToCheck}"`);
}
}
```

Hope this helps!